# Greeting on Yom Hashoah

Tags: words, holocaust-shoah

What is the proper greeting on Yom hashoah?
I am not Jewish but do have some Jewish friends and would like to know how to greet them on this day of remembrance.

Comment: Hello -- while your question is thought provoking, as Yom Hashoah is not, strictly speaking, a religious holiday, it might be difficult to answer from within a context of Jewish law.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Robert and thanks for this first question and your sensitivity. Great to have you with us!

Answer (score 0):

Yom Hashoa is the official Israeli Remembrance Day and it only reflects governmental aspects, not interpersonal.

While on a political level, there are lots of ceremonies, no change in personal conduct is expected, like no changes in clothes, talk, activities, greetings etc.